# UIWebView Zoom for a particular Point in iOS

Tags: ios, svg, uiwebview, zooming

All,

I am using UIWebview in iOS for displaying a SVG file, I am able to do that.

When i click on a particular Node (For example Text Tag), I want to zoom to particular point in UIWebView.

How can i achieve it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134576/enable-zooming-pinch-on-uiwebview

Comment: I think this functionality is default there if we click textfield in web view, it will zoom and textfield is visible above keyboard.