# UIWebView's property scalesPageToFit = YES not working correctly on larger images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, imagedownload

In an iphone app i have a webview in which i want to preview some image downloaded from internet, my problem is that the some images are not viewed as to fit in the frame of webview, but most do. I think this is due to the fact that those images are too large. Am i doing something wrong? Please help

What i want is simply **loading image in webview to fit the frame of webview**. You can provide me some other code, but need to be regarding webview not imageview.

Here is the code i am using.

```
self.documentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.folio3.com/corp/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Entrance_A-3.jpg"]];
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.webView loadData:self.documentData MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Plus here is the screenshot of output (clearly shows scroll indicators i-e image is not fit in webview's frame)[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: If anyone wants a better answer along the same lines as Ammar's: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4670989/1861181

Comment: You could try using WKWebView instead of UIWebView, it worked for me in a similar case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using html content for WebView, like the following code

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style='margin:0px; padding:0px;'>
   <img src='<your_image_url>' 
        style='max-width:320px; max-height:460px;' 
        alt='Your_Image_Name'/>
</body>
</html>
```

To re-size image use CSS (cascaded style sheet) styling, play with the these style properties in image style attribute

> **max-width,  min-width, width, max-height, min-height & height**

Comment: OK but where in the iOS does this go? How is it implemented ?

Answer (score 4):

First Check and set frame of `UIWebView` in `viewDidLoad:` like bellow..

```
webView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

after use this Delegate method and set `scalesPageToFit` property like bellow..

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;//set here
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @iMemon see this answers and try that also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350135/uiwebview-wont-zoom-even-after-setting-scalespagetofit-to-yes :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution builds on the answer from Ammar Hasan. Instead of the original...

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
[self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

...you can do this:

```
NSString *photoWrapper = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
 <html>\n\
    <head>\n\
        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" />\n\
        <style type=\"text/css\">\n\
            body {\n\
                margin: 0;\n\
                padding: 0;\n\
            }\n\
            img {\n\
                width: 100%%;\n\
            }\n\
        </style>\n\
    </head>\n\
    <body>\n\
        <img src=\"%@\" />\n\
    </body>\n\
</html>\
", URL];
[self.documentView loadHTMLString:photoWrapper baseURL:nil];
```

Now the image is scaled to the width of the web view, even when the web view is less than half the width of the image, which seems to be a limit that UIWebView imposes otherwise. The image can still be scaled by the user, which I wanted. You can override that by adding `minimum-scale` and `maximum-scale` to the viewport meta tag.